# How to find a Lyapunov function

Tags: nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, nonlinear-dynamics, lyapunov-functions

I have the following system: $$\dot{x_1} = x_2(x_3-2) \\ \dot{x_2} = x_1(x_3-2) \\ \dot{x_3}=-x_3^3 $$ and I want to determine its equilibrium points together with their stability. To find the equilibrium points, I wrote $$x_2=0 \text{ or } x_3=2 \\ x_1=0 \text{ or } x_3=2  \\ x_3 =0$$
Thus, only equilibrium point $x^*$ for the system is the origin $0$. I found $\det{Df(0)} = 0$ so I expect that the origin is a non-hyperbolic equilibrium point, probably asymptotically stable. To determine its type, I want to find a Liapunov function. Now, I assumed I can take $V(x)=c_1x_1^2 +c_2x_2^2+c_3x_3^3$ for some positive constants $c_i$. We have $V(0)=0$ and $V(x)>0$ for any $x \neq 0$. Then, $$\dot{V}(x)=\nabla V\cdot f(x) = 2c_1x_1x_2(x_3-2)+2c_2x_1x_2(x_3-2)-2c_3x_3^4.$$

$(\star )$ Now, let $c_1=c_2=1$ and $c_3 =2$ so that we get $$\dot{V}(x)=4x_1x_2(x_3-2)-4x_3^4.$$

However, I do not know how to determine the sign of this expression to conclude the result. I want to ask

1. Is it enough to find a Lyapunov function which is always positive or negative to say that $x^*$ is stable/unstable/asymptotically stable?
2. Similar to the first question but am I allowed to set arbitary values for $c_i$'s? (The $\star$ part)
3. How can I deduce the result?

Comment: Check the linearization of your system at the origin, it is unstable.

Comment: I found the eigenvalues of the linearization as $\pm2,0$. Then what do I do?

Comment: You have one positive and one negative, it is the saddle point. The linearization is unstable, thus there is no Lyapunov function with negative-definite time derivative.

Comment: It is not really clear what is the question. As we have discussed, your linearization has a positive eigenvalue, and thus the origin is unstable (see Lyapunov's indirect method). Then there are no Lyapunov functions with negative-definite time derivative. What remains unanswered in the question?

Comment: @Arastas I checked the indirect method but it says if there is an eigenvalue with zero real part then we cannot make any conclusions. So, I have one, I still do not know how to check the stability of the origin.

Comment: sorry, but it is wrong. The correct formulation is the following: if all are negative (concerning the real part), then stable; if at least one is positive, then unstable; otherwise, linearization fails. See, e.g., Theorem 3.2 here: https://www.egr.msu.edu/~khalil/NonlinearControl/Slides-Full/Lect_4.pdf

Comment: See also the Chetaev instability theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equations in their current form, don't need a Lyapunov function for their stability analysis. After all, it seems the system is ill-defined. Here is why.

The third equation describing $x_3$ is totally independent from the other two, and can/should be eliminated:
$$\dot{x}_3=-x_3^3\implies x_3(t)=\pm\frac1{\sqrt{2t-c_3}}$$
where $c_3$ is a constant that has to be determined according to the initial conditions:
$$x_3(0)^2=\frac1{-c_3}\implies x_3(t)=\pm\frac1{\sqrt{2t+1/x_3^2(0)}}$$
Anyway, you still can't get rid of the $\pm$ sign. Because both answers satisfy the equation in its current form.

For the other two, you can simply divide them like this:
$$\begin{matrix}\dot{x}_1=x_2(x_3-2)\\ \dot{x}_2=x_1(x_3-2)\end{matrix}
\implies\frac{\dot{x}_1}{\dot{x}_2}=\frac{x_2}{x_1}$$
But $\frac{\dot{x}_1}{\dot{x}_2}=\frac{d x_1/dt}{d x_2/dt}=\frac{d x_1}{d x_2}$, which implies
$$x_1 d x_1=x_2 d x_2\overset{\int}{\implies}x_1^2=x_2^2+c_2\quad\text{i.e.}\;x_2=\sqrt{x_1^2+c}$$
As you see, the equations are not independent. So the stability of the system cannot be determined without further information. If you put the above result into the first equation and also replace $x_3$ by the function we obtained for it, we will have a single ODE for $x_1$. I omit the rest.

Comment: And by the way, if you solve the equation for $x_1$ it gives: $$x_1(t)=\pm\sqrt{c}\sinh\left(-2 t + \sqrt{2 t+1/x_3^2(0)} + c_1\right)$$ where $c_1$ is determined by $x_1(0)$ but still, $c$ is dependent on $x_2$

Comment: We do not need to write all these solutions to study the stability/instability of the system, it can be done simpler.

Comment: @Arastas please note that, as I said, the system is ill-defined. The solution is to illustrate this fact. Before studying the stability, you should ask yourself a simple question: does this system have an equilibrium point? (It doesn't! Can you tell why?)

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what do you mean. It is probable that we mean something different when we discuss stability and equilibrium. Since there is the tag "Lyapunov-functions", I consider the problem in the context of Control Science. From this point of view, it is a nonlinear system that has one isolated unstable equilibrium at the origin.

Comment: @Arastas just look at this equation $$x_3(t)=\pm\frac1{\sqrt{2t+1/x_3^2(0)}}$$ and note that $x_3(t)$ cannot be zero at $t=0$. Do you get what I mean by ill-defined?

Comment: The solution of $\dot{x}(t) = -x^3(t)$ with the initial condition $x(0)=0$ is $x(t)\equiv 0$.

Answer (score 2):

If the system is stable, then there exists a ball centered at the origin such that all trajectories starting in this ball are bounded. Let us consider the initial condition $$x(0) = \begin{bmatrix}x_{1}(0) \\ x_{2}(0) \\ 0\end{bmatrix}.$$
From the system's dynamics, it follows that for these initial conditions $x_3(t)\equiv 0$ for all $t\ge0$. Then the dynamics of $x_1(t)$, $x_2(t)$ is
$$\begin{bmatrix}\dot{x}_{1}(t) \\ \dot{x}_{2}(t) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -2 \\ -2 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}{x}_{1}(t) \\ {x}_{2}(t) \end{bmatrix}.$$
This linear system is unstable, and thus all trajectories with nonzero initial conditions such that $x_3(0)=0$ are unbounded. The system is unstable.

Comment: This answer is based on the assumption that $x_3(0)=0$ which is flawed by the way

Comment: This assumption is sufficient to show that the system is unstable. Because if it is stable, it must be stable also for $x_3(0)=0$. If it is not the case, the system is unstable.

Answer (score 2):

One can precisely describe all trajectories of the system with  (almost) no computation. As polfosol said, the dynamics of $x_3$ is independent from $x_1$, $x_2$. Without explicitly computing the solution, we can immediately say that $x_3(t)\to0$ as $t\to+\infty$.

Next, we call $u:=x_1+x_2$ and $v:=x_1-x_2$ and find that
$$\begin{cases}
\dot u &= (x_3-2)u\\
\dot v &= (2-x_3)v.
\end{cases}$$
Hence, for $t$ large, $\dot u\sim -2u$ and $\dot v\sim 2v$
and therefore $u\to0$
and $v$ (which cannot change sign) satisfies
$v\to+\infty$ if $v(0)>0$, $v\to-\infty$ if $v(0)<0$
and $v\equiv0$ if $v(0)=0$  (these can easily be proved rigorously).

Reverting to the original variables, we conclude that any trajectory tends to $\infty$ approaching the line
$$x_1+x_2=0\\
x_3=0$$
except for the ones starting from the plane $x_1-x_2=0$ (stable manifold), which approach the equilibrium $(0,0,0)$.